# How do I install a Minecraft addon on iPadOS?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-addons

How do I install a Minecraft addon on iPadOS? I have never played anything on a phone or tablet in my life, let alone Minecraft, but yesterday my daughter asked me to install [this addon](https://modbay.org/mods/646-radiums-armament.html), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft"…](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded Minecraft issues are on-topic.

Comment: This isn't even a question about modded Minecraft. Addons are completely different from mods, and are officially supported by Microsoft/Mojang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instructions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/gettingstarted?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable&tabs=iOS#installing-add-on-instructions). (Found the link to that [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/creator).)

> 1. Launch Minecraft.
> 2. Click on the world or add-on file you want to open (URL, e-mail attachment, etc.).
> 3. Your device will prompt you to open the file with Minecraft.
> 4. Click `Open` in Minecraft; This will launch Minecraft with your selected file.
>
> - If you're opening a .mcworld that contains add-ons, the game will notify you that you've successfully imported the world. It will then be available from the "Play" menu.
> - If you're opening a .mcpack, a pop-up notification will alert you that you've successfully imported the pack. Depending on the pack type, this will then be available when editing worlds in either the Behavior Pack tab or Resource Pack tab.

Assuming the download links on that website work correctly, those instructions should work.

(I would strongly caution you to be very careful when attempting to download these addons. I followed the download links, and there are a very large amount of ads to get past in order to download the content. I would encourage your daughter to find a different addon to play if possible, or [play on a server](https://mcsrvstat.us/bedrock/pocket.havoc.games:19132) that uses guns).